# Syntactic analysis - prolog

Tags: prolog, dcg

I have a Definite Clause Grammar: S → a S b | ɛ .

This was also written as the following rules: `s --> [a], s, [b].` and `s --> [].`

This was translated to Prolog as follows:

```
s --> [a], s, [b].   became   s([a|S2],R) :- s(S2,[b|R]).
s --> [].            became   s(S,S).
```

Can somebody tell me what the value of S2 is here? Where does S2 come from?

Comment: It is the tail of the list...

Comment: Could you provide a little more context? What are the rules on the left, perhaps a context-sensitive grammar?

Comment: They are Definite Clause Grammar. Initially it was : S → a S b | ɛ, then it becomes :  s --> [a], s, [b].
s --> [].

Comment: I took the liberty of editing these things into your question. If you disagree with my edits, you can roll them back. To roll back an edit, click on the "edited ... ago" link. That takes you to the revision history, where you can roll back to earlier versions if you want. I believe, however, that these edits make the question better fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thanks for your help S.L. Barth it's ok. I am juste trying to understand what this "S2" could contain. Could it contain a "a", or a "b", or an empty list "[]" ?

Comment: It could contain all of these, even the empty list `[]`. It all depends on what the input list is. Edited my answer to give a few examples, including the case where `S2` is `[]`.

Comment: Ok, actually S2, can only contain a or b or an empty list but I think not x,y or z, because of the rule "s --> [a], s, [b]." which only allows the "a" and "b" letters. Isn't that true ?

Comment: I've updated the answer. It should fail _eventually_. However, during the step where it is provided with `[a,x,y,z]` it will bind `S2` to `[x,y,z]`. Only in a later step will it look at that `[x,y,z]` itself, and notice that it does not match.

Comment: I think part of the confusion is how the `s([a|S2],R) :- s(S2,[b|R]).` rule is interpreted by Prolog. Prolog works different from your grammar. In the grammar, the entire rule is applied immediately. Prolog applies the rule in two parts. The first time, Prolog sees that it has "a followed by something", and matches S2 to that "something". Only later does it look at what's in S2, and realizes that it has illegal values.

Comment: ok thanks. Last question, what is "R" useful for ? When I make the calls in the console, I notice that R. gives the elements which are refused : ?- s([a,a,b,b,x],R).
R = [x] ;
R = [a, a, b, b, x]. But to work there is one condition, the code "s(S,S)." must be added.

Comment: my problem is how to be able to make the transformation from "s --> [a], s, [b]." to "s([a|S2],R) :- s(S2,[b|R])."

Comment: You could think of `R` as an output variable here. What happens is that `R` is not assigned at first. The program recursively descends, one item at a time, until it reaches the `s(S,S)` rule. At that point, it sets the righthand value equal to the lefthand value. I'll update the answer, hopefully that will clarify it.

Comment: Sorry, what are the steps to go from "S → a S b | ɛ" to "s([a|S2],R) :- s(S2,[b|R]).". I need a method to get the second code starting from the first.

Comment: Excuse me, I don't really know how to proceed, do I have to open a new topic ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this is a program to determine if a list is of the form a<sup>n</sup> . X . b<sup>n</sup>, where a<sup>n</sup> means `n` iterations of `a`, and similarly, b<sup>n</sup> means `n` iterations of `b`.

```
s --> [a], s, [b]. becomes s([a|S2],R) :- s(S2,[b|R]).
s --> [].          becomes s(S,S).
```

Here `S2` is the middle of the list, a free variable that a part of the list can be bound to.

Naming it `S2` is completely arbitrary. It could also have been called `S`. 
The only thing it should not be called is `R`, as that is already used for another variable in that statement.

What matters is what is bound to it - the tail of the list. If this predicate is tried on any list starting with `a`, then `S2` will be bound to the tail.

A few examples to illustrate it:
If the input was `[a,a,b,b]`, the value of `S2` would be `[a,b,b]`.
If the input was `[a]`, the value of S2 would be the empty list `[]`.
If the input was `[a,x,y,z]`, the value of `S2` would be `[x,y,z]`.
If the input was `[b,c,d,e]`, then it would not match, and `S2` would not be bound to anything; instead, the predicate would fail.

Note that `[a,x,y,z]` actually matches the predicate, despite the fact that it is not of the form a<sup>n</sup> . X . b<sup>n</sup>.
The rule only looks at the first item, `a`, and notices that that matches. So it derives `s([x,y,z],[b|R])`. Then it will try to continue verifying the input. Only in a later derivation step will it notice that `[x,y,z]` does not start with `a`.

Let's go through this step by step.

- First we have:
  `s([a,x,y,z],R) :- s([x,y,z],[b|R]).`
  This works, and Prolog binds S2 to `[x,y,z]`.
- Then it gets `s([x,y,z],R)`, but it cannot match that to `s([a|S2])`, because it does not start with `a`, and so this time the rule fails.
- Now it tries the next rule: `s(S,S)`. It fills in: `s([x,y,z],[x,y,z]).`
  With this, it goes back to its earlier call, and tries to match `s([x,y,z],[x,y,z])` to its earlier rule `s([x,y,z],[b|R])`.
- It cannot match the `[x,y,z]` on the rigthand side to `[b|R]` because it does not start with `b`. And this is where the rule fails - Prolog has decided that the string is not of the form a<sup>n</sup>.b<sup>n</sup>.

To see how `R` is used, let's look at a trace of a list that *does* match.

```
s([a,a,b,b],R):-s([a,b,b],[b|R]). /* We haven't got a value for R yet. */
s([a,b,b],R):-s([b,b],[b|R]).     /* We haven't got a value for R yet. */
s([b,b],[b,b]).                   /* Stop condition for the recursion. */
```

At this point, the righthand side is instantiated to `[b,b]`.
Prolog had `s([a,b,b],[b|R])` in the previous step, and it can now make this succeed by setting `R=[b]`.
It then further unwinds the recursion, filling in values for the righthand side of the rule and applying these values to the lefthand side. Eventually it returns to where it started, and has the value `s([a,a,b,b],[a,a,b,b])`.